# Start receiving again Socket Error

Tags: c#, sockets

I've been stuck on a problem for some time now, when sending a request from client to server, the server responds with data pulled from sql database and client receives it, everything going fine. The problem is when the client again asks for data from server, which gives me following error: Objectreference not set to an instance of object. Thing is, when adding data to my database, the server can receive multiple requests. According to my try catches, the error occurs when my SendCallback calls my method to start receive data.

```
private static void BeginAccept()
    {
        listener.Listen(5);

        Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener));
        t.Start();
    }

private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        handler.BeginReceive(recBuf, 0, bufsize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), handler);

        Console.WriteLine("client connected"  );
    }

private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data...");

            string content = string.Empty;
            string[] pieces = null;
            string[] delimiters = { "|" };
            /*StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState; */// Calling the socket from AcceptCallback.
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            sb.Clear();
            int dataReceived = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                if (dataReceived > 0)
                {
                   sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recBuf, 0,dataReceived));
                    if (content.IndexOf("<!ReqDB>") > -1)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Following data received: " + content);
                            pieces = null;
                            pieces = content.Split(delimiters, StringSplitOptions.None);
                            sb = null;
                            Console.WriteLine("ReqDB received!!");
                            Int64 ID = Int64.Parse(pieces[0]);
                            RetrieveDataFromDB(handler, ID);
     //Some other irrelevant code....
```

RetrieveDataFromDB pulls data out of the database, converts it and calls Send(handler, data);

```
private static void Send(Socket handler, string data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
    }

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesSend = handler.EndSend(ar);
            handler.BeginReceive(recBuf, 0, bufsize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), handler);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Line 197: "+e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Somewhere, probably when SendCallback executes handler.beginReceive and the method is called, the error occurs, and I do not know where the error is, or what is causing the error. I assume it is the handler, though I do not understand why it's causing it.

Comment: Where does the error happen? Pls point to the line it happens.

Comment: Don't know where the error came from, I reformatted my code a bit, and got another error caused by a stringbuilder which I set = null; After I changed that it worked without a problem. Oh well, problem solved.